# how i can pass a tuple on contractor solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

hello i want to pass this parameters on constractor when i deploy the smart contract on remixIDE
I want to know how i can pass this params on constractor .
hello i want to pass this parameters on constractor when i deploy the smart contract on remixIDE
I want to know how i can pass this params on constractor .

```
struct NewPoolParams {
    IVault vault;
    string name;
    string symbol;
    IERC20 token0;
    IERC20 token1;
    uint256 normalizedWeight0;
    uint256 normalizedWeight1;
    uint256 swapFeePercentage;
    uint256 pauseWindowDuration;
    uint256 bufferPeriodDuration;
    bool oracleEnabled;
    address owner;
}

constructor(NewPoolParams memory params)
    // Base Pools are expected to be deployed using factories. By using the factory address as the action
    // disambiguator, we make all Pools deployed by the same factory share action identifiers. This allows for
    // simpler management of permissions (such as being able to manage granting the 'set fee percentage' action in
    // any Pool created by the same factory), while still making action identifiers unique among different factories
    // if the selectors match, preventing accidental errors.
    Authentication(bytes32(uint256(msg.sender)))
    BalancerPoolToken(params.name, params.symbol)
    BasePoolAuthorization(params.owner)
    TemporarilyPausable(params.pauseWindowDuration, params.bufferPeriodDuration)
{
    _setOracleEnabled(params.oracleEnabled);
    _setSwapFeePercentage(params.swapFeePercentage);

    bytes32 poolId = params.vault.registerPool(IVault.PoolSpecialization.TWO_TOKEN);

    // Pass in zero addresses for Asset Managers
    IERC20[] memory tokens = new IERC20[](2);
    tokens[0] = params.token0;
    tokens[1] = params.token1;
    params.vault.registerTokens(poolId, tokens, new address[](2));

    // Set immutable state variables - these cannot be read from during construction
    _vault = params.vault;
    _poolId = poolId;

    _token0 = params.token0;
    _token1 = params.token1;

    _scalingFactor0 = _computeScalingFactor(params.token0);
    _scalingFactor1 = _computeScalingFactor(params.token1);

    // Ensure each normalized weight is above them minimum and find the token index of the maximum weight
    _require(params.normalizedWeight0 >= _MIN_WEIGHT, Errors.MIN_WEIGHT);
    _require(params.normalizedWeight1 >= _MIN_WEIGHT, Errors.MIN_WEIGHT);

    // Ensure that the normalized weights sum to ONE
    uint256 normalizedSum = params.normalizedWeight0.add(params.normalizedWeight1);
    _require(normalizedSum == FixedPoint.ONE, Errors.NORMALIZED_WEIGHT_INVARIANT);

    _normalizedWeight0 = params.normalizedWeight0;
    _normalizedWeight1 = params.normalizedWeight1;
    _maxWeightTokenIndex = params.normalizedWeight0 >= params.normalizedWeight1 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlzSz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Interface types are represented as addresses, and other values are scalar.

Remix IDE accepts a `tuple` input as an array.

So in this specific case, that could be for example:

```
["0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF", "name", "symbol", "0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF", "0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, true, "0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF"]
```

*Note: This constructor performs calls on the specified addresses, so make sure you're connected to a network where these contracts exists.*